# insert update only modified fields over 2 servers mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 sql servers on 2 diferent locations.

One is a web server and the other a crm system.

People update and register on web, when they do changes i need to insert or update the changes to my crm server.

I have a view on web server where i can select from but i need to

```
insert into on duplicate update only fields that changed and then in a description 
show     
wich fields were updated?
```

I have no clue how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

INSERT INTO table ON DUPLICATE UPDATE table SET field = value WHERE field != 'value'
and you might want to look into this to see if there are [Affected rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can not determine the differences on fields after changing them.

You can however select and store the contents prior to the update and then compare it with the new contents.

The question then becomes: Do you need the differences **per column**?

- If yes: Pre-select and do the difference yourself (in the
  application).
- If no: Use the method described by @Ogelami (and accept his answer :)

On a side note: The Pre-Select thing won't work as well, when you start using several mysql servers, since you might run into issues with drifting data (ie one server is behind in inserted data). When this occurs, the method will get a bit more complex.